# Removing a substring from a char array without using any libraries in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, null, substring

I am a computer science first year student and our teachers gave a binary pattern search task to do. We have to remove a substring from a string without using any libraries and built-ins like(memmove or strstr). Our only hint is that its something to do with '\0'. I don't see how we are going to achive this because as i know the null character only ends a string not removes it. And given an unknown input it gets even harder to get around. I need help about the usage of null character. EDIT: Oh and also we are not allowed to create new arrays. EDIT2: The problem is much more complicated if you are here for the solution read the comments under this thread and the marked solution's also.

Comment: Hint is useful only if substring is ending the original string. In which case you will end the original string before the substring using `\0` char.

Comment: In order to focus this question more on the part you have a problem with, please show the code environment. I.e. make a [mre] of the program which provides the string to process in a suitable way, has a part to be extended by the removal implementation and in the end can output the result of the removal.

Comment: Note that I do not assume that the substring to remove is at the end of the input string. The hint on zero is probably only a hint on how to handle a chain of characters and also on how to end a string after it has been shortened, in order to avoid the last part (of the length of the removed string) being repeated in the output. Please correct me, if anything in your assignment supports the assumption of the substring being at the end. If you can give examples of input strings and subsbtrings it will get obvious, even without an explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah thats the tricky part we cannot make any assumptions about the place of the substring. Moreover the task is much more larger than just removing a substring.We have to do it recursively until every substring pattern that we search for is gone from our given input. İ.e. "10011" if we remove "01" from this string a new "01" would apper in the leftover part and we have to remove it also.

Comment: You should definitly [edit] that helpful additional information into your question, because for example the existing answer demonstrates that the way it currently is asked is easily misleading and results in answers which are off the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings are "null terminated" which means they are considered to end wherever a null (written `'\0'` in C) appears.

If I start with the string "Stack Overflow" and I overwrite the space with `'\0'`, I now have the string "Stack".  The storage for "Overflow" still exists, but it is not part of the string according to C functions like `strlen()`, `printf()` etc.  In fact, if I hold a pointer to the "O" part of the original string, it will be just as if there are two strings: "Stack" and "Overflow", and you can still use both of them.

It's like if I come to where you live and I build a huge wall across the road just before your house.  The road is now shortened, and people on my side of it won't know you are there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and a clear analogy :D. But my problem also gets more complicated here. Maybe my question is a bit misleading but i also want to print the part coming after the null. Let me clarify with an example. I want to remove "Over" from the "Stack Overflow" but putting and \0 before the "Over" would also remove the "flow". I want the final output to be "Stack flow".

Comment: Then you'll have to overwrite "over " with "flow\0" unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose oh wow that might work. I have been thinking about this problem too much that i missed that point. Omg i am shocked rn thanks.

Comment: @MustafaÇığGökpınar: I can think of two approaches.  First you can create a pointer to the "f" which gives you the string "flow", and replace the "O" with null to get "Stack ".   Then you have two strings and you need to print both to get "Stack flow".  Or you can do what Bob suggested if it has to be a single string at the end.

Comment: For now i will try to implement the bob's solution as we are requested to return a char pointer. Thanks for all your help. I will mark your answer as the right solution and people can read the comment section for the real answer.